# javascript return value for ToolTip

Tags: javascript

I am using this value for to display it in tooltip .

```
return 'Date '+dateData[obj.x]+'value '+obj.y+'';
```

Is it possible to show in two lines (one for Date ) and (two for value)

This is the way i want to show

```
Date 12/23/45
value 23
```

But currently this is shown in a single line only

```
Date 12/23/45 value 23
```

I have tried this way , but this isn't working

```
return 'Date '+dateData[obj.x]+'value\n '+obj.y+'';
```

Comment: You've been on StackOverflow for nearly two months, and asked **67** previous questions. I've fixed the formatting in your question, but frankly if I'd looked at your profile first, I wouldn't have. You should be formatting things correctly by now. Please check out the handy **How to Format** box to the right of the question area. Worth a read, as is [the page linked](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) from the **[?]** just above the question area.

Comment: What kind of tooltip are you using? All I see above is a function returning a string. It matters, because some kinds of tooltips don't support multiple lines, and the way in which they're supported varies from tooltip to tooltip. For instance, your `\n` should be working in a [`title` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-title-attribute), if everything else is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return 'Date '+dateData[obj.x]+'<BR>value '+obj.y+'';
```

The br element’s purpose is very simple: it creates a line break within a block of text, leaving no padding or margins between the two blocks of text created by the line break. While it’s still perfectly valid to use this element in XHTML Strict pages (it’s not on the list of deprecated elements), you need to take care that you don’t misuse it, because:

It can be used in a presentational manner. For example, you might use a series of br elements in succession to create a new paragraph effect, instead of simply using a or a blockquote, and applying CSS to set the layout.

Using br elements becomes a real headache if, later, you want to correct visual inconsistencies and have to sweep through hundreds of files to strip them out.

There are some exceptional cases in which you might be forced to use a br element:

In poetry, a new line requires just that: a new line. You can’t use a p element in this case. (Evidently poetry wasn’t high on the list of markup requirements when the HTML recommendations were thrashed out!)

When you’re marking up a postal address, you may need to create single line breaks. However, with the advent of Microformats, there’s quite a well-established method for dealing with postal (and other) address types that avoids the use of the br while offering additional semantic richness. Refer to the section titled http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/hcard/ for more.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/br

I hope this has been a helpful article for you

Comment: haha sorry i may have been teasing with the article, but yea, by adding that text to your tooltip, its really adding HTML to it. \n is not a valid html control, <BR> is what you want